# Exclude items from a model - MVC/ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework-4

This is a follow up question to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11797814/using-viewmodels-and-linq-in-asp-net-mvc-4)

I have two models:

```
CarType.cs

//
// Holds types of car - this has a one to many relationship with Car class
//
[Table("tType")]
public class CarType
{
    [Key]
    public int type_id { get; set; }
    public int dealer_id { get; set; }
    public string type_name { get; set; }
    public string type_desc { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Car> Cars { get; set; }
}  


Car.cs

//
// Holds actual Cars
//

[Table("tCar")]
public class Car
{
    [Key]
    public int car_id { get; set; }
    public int dealer_id { get; set; }
    public int type_id { get; set; }
    public int car_order { get; set; }
    public string car_name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Rental> Rentals { get; set; }
    public virtual CarType CarType { get; set; }
}
```

I want to have a view model, where I can view car types, and how many of each car type I have within each Car Type class, so I've created a ViewModel:

```
public class SearchViewModel
{
    [Required]
    public DateTime From { get; set; }
    public int Nights { get; set; }
    public int dealer_id { get; set; }
    public IQueryable<CarType> CarTypes { get; set; }
    // CarTypes as above, has a one to many relationship with the class Car
}
```

Given a predeterminded list of actual cars (say preBookedCars), I want to remove the list of cars from the ViewObject so for example, if the model of CarType (including the one 2 many Cars) looked like this:

```
Mercedes (count = 3)
....Car 1
....Car 2
....Car 3
Ford (count = 3)
....Car 4
....Car 5
....Car 6
Citroen (count = 3)
....Car 7
....Car 8
....Car 9
```

Given a list of CARS, how would I EXCLUDE the list of cars from the CarType model - eg.

I have a list of: Car 1, Car 4, Car 8, Car 9 - so I would like the above model to show:

```
Mercedes (count = 2)
....Car 2
....Car 3
Ford (count = 2)
....Car 5
....Car 6
Citroen (count = 1)
....Car 7
```

I know it's something along the lines of (pseudo LINQ):

```
var freeCars = (db context).CarTypes
                        .Cars
                        .Except(preBookedCars)
```

Thank you for any help,

Mark

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779.aspx ?

Comment: I believe the code you need can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11092930/check-if-listt-contains-any-of-another-list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for, but if you're just trying to filter against the Cars collection in the CarType object, you can use something like this:

```
var preBookedCars = new List<int> { 1, 5, 9 };
var myCarType = new CarType();
var filteredCars = myCarType.Cars.Where(c => !preBookedCars.Contains(c.car_id));
```

This code can be adapted to be used where ever you need.